# Action on Google deploy tab returns 504

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

When trying to access `https://console.actions.google.com/project/*project-id*/release/` I get following error message:

[image: errror message actions on google]

If I open the developer console in Chrome and check for failed network calls it shows a 504 on `https://console.actions.google.com/m/actions/agents/versions/get?projectNumber=*project-number*` with this body:

[image: body of failed call]

I tried clearing my cache and tested on multiple browsers but since it also happens on other devices I guess this is a server issue.

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: I'm not seeing this currently, so it may have been an unusual transient issue.

Comment: I've not been able to load the page for 3days now, so I don't think it's a transient issue. I'm aware it's not a general outage since I'm able to access other projects.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue for a published Action.

According to Actions on Google support, it's because the cumulative size of all the versions of our action were causing that version request to timeout when it tries to pre-load them all at once.

The solution for me was to, raise a support request (I clicked the link in your screenshot, `Actions on Google Support`, included a screenshot of that message, request type `deployment issue` and a brief description of not being able to access the deploy/test  tabs) and then when support responded, they asked which versions to keep/delete. I said delete all except one version either side of the currently deployed version.

A note on preventing this - I couldn't find a consistent method for deleting versions/releases. I believe the versions created in Dialogflow by doing a `Publish A Version` can be deleted in Dialogflow. But versions created by releases in Actions on Google, have the delete options greyed out in Dialogflow, and I couldn't find where to do that in Actions on Google.